# Does anyone know how to use sip.js version 0.8 or higher with electron (desktop app) or with Ionic (mobile app)?

Tags: ionic-framework, electron, webrtc, sip

I am developing a web application for phone calls using sip.js for signaling and webrtc for media management. With browsers, everything works perfectly. Now we are trying to develop it for desktop using Electron (Chromium) and for mobile devices using ionic / cordova. For IOS cordova-plugin-iosrtc to have webrtc and for android native webrtc. Both mobile environments work perfectly with sip 0.7, but with identical or higher sip versions 0.8 none is able to acquire local media devices.

For example, **in electron**:

```
session.on ('trackAdded', function () {

    var pc = session.sessionDescriptionHandler.peerConnection;

    // Gets remote tracks
    var remoteStream = new MediaStream ();
    pc.getReceivers (). forEach (function (receiver) {
        remoteStream.addTrack (receiver.track);
    });

    remoteVideo.srcObject = remoteStream;
    remoteVideo.play ();

    // Gets local tracks
    alert (pc.getSenders ())
    var localStream = new MediaStream ();

    pc.getSenders (). forEach (function (sender) {
        localStream.addTrack (sender.track);
    });

    localVideo.srcObject = localStream;
    localVideo.play ();

});
```

**error**

```
Tue Nov 06 2018 16:17:33 GMT+0100 (CET) | 
sip.invitecontext.sessionDescriptionHandler | unable to acquire streams
LoggerFactory.print @ sip.js:516
LoggerFactory.(anonymous function) @ sip.js:530
Logger.(anonymous function) @ sip.js:525
(anonymous) @ sip.js:8816
sip.js:516 TypeError: pc.getSenders is not a function
at InviteClientContext.<anonymous> (telephoneservice.js:796)
at InviteClientContext.EventEmitter.emit (sip.js:662)
at SessionDescriptionHandlerObserver.trackAdded (sip.js:8963)
at SessionDescriptionHandler.<anonymous> (sip.js:8797)
at <anonymous>
```

Something similar happens with IOS ...

Good morning

Comment: which **electron version** ?

Comment: 1.8.4 electron version

Comment: it uses **Chrome 59.0.3071.115** and if I'm not mistaken the **getSenders method in this version of chrome was not implemented till version 64 of Chrome**. Check [this](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5644723490390016).

Answer (score 1):

The version of electron you are using (**1.8.4**) doesn't support the **sip.js 0.8 new api** which in its turn *supports all the **latest versions of major browser***.

[For changes since 0.7.x, see the release notes on GitHub](https://github.com/onsip/SIP.js/releases/tag/0.8.0)

> Session Description Handler replaces the media handler. See the new docs for more information. This is an API breaking change from 0.7.X.

That's why you are getting this

```
sip.js:516 TypeError: pc.getSenders is not a function
```

Because at that time (**electron 1.8.4/Chrome 59.0.3071.115**) this function wasn't implemented yet.

[CHROME WEBRTC M64](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/discuss-webrtc/fIWg5n67xHo/QIhRnv6vBgAJ)

> PSA: addTrack(), removeTrack(), ontrack and getSenders()
>
> Significant portions of the RTP Media API are shipping for spec-compliant ways of handling the streams and tracks of an RTCPeerConnection.
>
> The new APIs, while not fully featured yet (more details here), allow applications to move away from legacy addStream()/removeStream()/getLocalStreams().
>
> Added to RTCPeerConnection: addTrack(), removeTrack(), getSenders() and ontrack.
>
> New interface: RTCRtpSender (track attribute only).

Comment: Do you know how it works in ionic-webview for mobile app version??

Comment: @ElLoko36 add your ionic/cordova mobile app with sip.js 0.8  **output** to your **question** to debug your problems